# Excel - Return name from list based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel-formula

This is my 1st post here (and not allowed to paste images). I have been trying to solve this issue for a couple of days with no luck. I'm working on an Excel spreadsheet for a game and cannot return a name based on multiple criteria. See below:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylVts.jpg)

I am trying to return, for example, the name of the Guardian with the highest amount of games played.

I've tried Index/match/sumproduct combinations but I can't figure this one out. Can you help me?

```
=index(Data!$A:$H,match((1,Data!B:B=Overview!B12)*(Data!C:C=Overview!B23)),0),1)
=MAX(IF(Data!B:B=Overview!B12,Data!C:C))
```

I'm thinking if I could join these two formulas together I might be able to make it work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  To avoid getting down-voted and/or flagged, you should add you code to show that you have done some work, and mention the specific place where you are getting an error.

Comment: In addition to the above, if you need help, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try this **array formula**:

```
=INDEX(Data!$A1:$A99,MATCH(MAX(Data!$C$1:$C$99*(Data!$B$1:$B$99=B12)),
  Data!$C$1:$C$99*(Data!$B$1:$B$99=B12),0))
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Notice that we should avoid using *"full columns"* in array formulas because they would introduce the computation of huge arrays and hence would slow down the formulas. I limit it here to 99 rows, use a limit that is big enough to span your data.